# did mistakes vs did badly

Tags: phrase-usage

As I understand, "did mistakes" is not used but I need to use the second sentence. Could you explain why?

> Jackie **did mistakes** in his test and had to take it again.
>
> Jackie **did badly** in his test and had to take it again.

TIA

Comment: You should say "made mistakes". "Did/performed badly/poorly" is fine as well.

Comment: The reason is that the verb we use with "mistakes" is _make_, not  _do_. I realise that this is simply restating your question, but **there is no other explanation**. It's just the way those particular words happen to behave in English.